# How do I change the name and description of a wizard page from within InitializeWizard?

Tags: inno-setup

I am moving code from `CurPageChanged` to `InitializeWizard`.
In `CurPageChanged` I could do this if Inno has changed to the page I wanted modify the name and descripton for:

```
WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'A message about your license';
WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := 'The message here';
```

But I can't do something similar from `InitializeWizard` without specifying the page I want to change the caption for. I have looked at the Inno Setup source but I can't figure out what I need to access. How can I change the name and description of a wizard page?

I would have thought something like `WizardForm.LicensePage.PageNameLabel.Caption` but that doesn't work. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. Is there an easier way? I might need to add translations for the name and description as well.

Comment: If you need to do this for translations, then the best would be to use the [`[Languages]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm) section and prepare the `*.isl` file instead of doing this manually for the whole wizard by your own.

Comment: When I test that, I get an *"An attempt was made to access WizardForm before it has been created"*. So it is not a matter of what to access but rather how Inno Setup works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a `Messages` section in your script:

```
[Messages]
WizardLicense = A message about your license
LicenseLabel = The message here
```

The way it is supposed to work to support multiple languages is like this:

```
[Languages]
Name: en; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: de; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Messages]
en.WizardLicense = A message about your license
en.LicenseLabel = The message here
de.WizardLicense = (German translation)
de.LicenseLabel = (Another translation..)
```

You can of course modify a copy of the corresponding .isl file and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks I actually ended up doing that. I am still curious as to how I'd do it from the [Code] section, what the identifiers are to access that area of the form. Can I access an arbitrary form's description and change it from a procedure?

Comment: @test - You're welcome. All that can be accessed from code is documented [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses) (see 'TWizardForm' near the bottom).

Comment: I did look at that, that's how I was able to do `WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption`, but I don't understand how to do it when I need to specify a form, like if I want to change wpLicense PageNameLabel I don't understand how I can do that.

Comment: @test - I don't think I understand. The way you commented (i.e. `WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption`) is the way to access it. I don't know any other way..

Comment: What I'm saying is, PageNameLabel could be for any wizard page.

Comment: @test - Ah! Yes, very true. It's trial and error I guess. If where any of those are used is documented, I'm not aware of it.